# Open and Closed covering

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff and totally disconnected space and $A$ be a closed subset of $X$ contained in an open set $U$. Then we can find a finite set $\{V_1,\cdots,V_n\}$, where each $V_i$ is open as well as closed in $X$ such that $A \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^n V_i \subseteq U$.

I understand that $A$ will be compact, therefore there will be a finite open cover of $A$ but why both open and closed. Also, why contained in $U$? What is the role of totally disconnected space here for getting open and closed covering?

Answer (score 3):

Every locally compact Hausdorff space which is totally disconnected admits a basis consisting of clopen sets. You can find this fact on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-dimensional_space) and you can find a proof on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37392/totally-disconnected-and-zero-dimensional-spaces). Using this you can cover $U$ by clopen sets and using the compactness of $X$ you can choose a finite subcover $\{V_1,\ldots,V_n\}$ consisting of clopen sets. This gives you the desired inclusions: 
$A\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i\subseteq U$.